# Center a sprite regardless of parent sprite

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

In my game I have a popup window that popups relative to a sprite you clicked. In that popup there is a button that when you touch it, it brings up another popup window that is just confirms the button press. My question is how do I center the second popup window so it is always in the center of the screen regardless of where the parent is on the screen? As it is now its position is relative to the parent.

Thanks Very Much

Comment: Please share your second popup window creation code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check your new popup position using "convertToWorldSpace" method. It will brings to you the position of the popup sprite relative to screen.
Then, subtract this position in your new popup position.

to use convertToWorldSpace:

```
[parentPopup convertToWorldSpace:newPopup];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can popup second window on the first view...

Comment: Your answer is a little short - can you provide more information / examples?